How is this sentence exactly divided?

表情は手で隠れて見えなかった。だからこの笑いがどういう種類のものなのか、黒鳥には判断がつかない。
けれど、これこそが天道の正直な気持ちなのだろう。
(面白くて、楽しくて笑っているわけではない―多分）
だって先ほどから天道には自重とか、悔恨とか、もどかしさとか、そういう自責では贖えないことへの感情を感じるからだ。

All of this is narrated by one person who is observing another character acting weird.
What I'm stuck is the meaning of the last sentence.

だって先ほどから天道には

After all, from before, in 天道

感情を感じるからだ。

Because I felt x emotion in him
What I'm stumbled is this part:

自重とか、悔恨とか、もどかしさとか、そういう自責では贖えないことへ

How is exactly the sentence divided?  "Are 自重とか、悔恨とか、もどかしさとか" describing 感情?
or is it more like 、そういう自責 is describing 自重とか、悔恨とか、もどかしさとか?
"そういう自責では贖えないことへの感情" should be at least "An emotion toward something that can't be atoned with self reproach"

Xへの感情 is "feelings toward X", and it's typically used like 彼への感情 ("feelings toward him"). In your sentence, this X part happens to be a fairly long clause nominalized with こと:

自重とか、悔恨とか、もどかしさとか、そういう自責では贖えないこと
(the fact) that he cannot make amends by (mere) self-reproaching such as restraint, regret or frustration

Here, 自重, 悔恨 and もどかしさ are listed as examples of 自責.
You correctly understand the rest of the sentence:

だって先ほどから天道にはXへの感情を感じるからだ。
That's because, since earlier, I've noticed Tendo's feelings towards X.

Therefore:

だって先ほどから天道には自重とか、悔恨とか、もどかしさとか、そういう自責では贖えないことへの感情を感じるからだ。
That's because, since earlier, I've noticed Tendo's feelings towards the fact that he cannot make amends (for what he has done) by (mere) self-reproaching such as restraint, regret or frustration.

If I guessed correctly, Tendo has done something really bad, but he is a very proud person who rarely apologizes. Even so, from his appearance, the speaker feels that he has realized it won't suffice to merely show self-restraint or frustration as a sign of "I'm sorry".
